# Downloading image from android, guaranteed to get it

Tags: android, web-services, soap, download, ksoap2

I have an android app which interacts with a web service. I download an image from the service, as a base64 string. This is the process:

::App polls for wifi every 10 seconds

::Within wifi > sends request to get any new images

::Server gets request, processes image, updates a database (all fairly quick)

::Server converts image to base64 and returns the string

::App saves image

Simple enough yes? The problem I have, is with the app going into wifi range briefly, then dropping out before it gets a response. This means the image is said to be downloaded in the database, when it isn't (big problem in this system).

Is there a good way to make sure the response goes through? Is my best option to make a second web method, which updates the database, which is only called from the app AFTER it's downloaded the image?

I'm making these calls using SOAP, the ksoap2 import.

Is the way I put down good, or is there a better way?

CallSoap.java:

```
public String Call(String variable1)
{

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,OPERATION_NAME);
    PropertyInfo pi=new PropertyInfo();
    pi.setName("variable1");
    pi.setValue(variable1);
    pi.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(pi);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
    SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);
    Object response=null;
    try

    {

        httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

        response = envelope.getResponse();

    }

    catch (Exception exception)

    {

        response=exception.toString();

    }


    return response.toString();
}
```

Caller.java

```
public class Caller  extends Thread 
{

public CallSoap cs;
public String variable1= "variable1";

public void run()
{
    try
    {
    cs=new CallSoap();  
    String resp=cs.Call(variable1);
    MySOAPCallActivity.rslt=resp;
    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MySOAPCallActivity.rslt=ex.toString();  
    }


}
}
```

main class:

```
try{

                rslt="START";
                Caller c=new Caller();
                c.variable1=variable1;
                c.join();
                c.start();
                while(rslt=="START")
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(10);
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex){
            }
```

Comment: THis is actually a classic CS problem called the "Last Messenger Problem".  You may be interested in googling that.

Comment: You could do an md5 check on the image once it is downloaded, this would ensure not only that it is downloaded fully, but also that it has not been corrupted during transfer.

Comment: @GabeSechan I googled, but that doesn't seem to be the name of that problem. Do you have a reference?

Comment: My old OS book from college.  Some quick googling also shows it called the "Byzantine General Problem" or "Two Generals Problem".  The brunt of it is two people need to communicate, and need to know if the last message got through.